# Get contents from a text file and save its values

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

I need to get the contents of a text file called `file.txt`. The contents of that file are:

> word1,word 2,word 3 1,another word 1,

I have a `config.php` which includes:

```
$file = "file.txt";
$value = explode(",", $file);
```

And `script.php` file which will execute other commands based on `$value` which includes:

```
if (count(explode($value, $chat))>1) {
```

After that, it will execute a command if the `$value` was detected in `$chat`. So, I need the `$value` to be a separate word in `file.txt`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Judging by the tags, you have an idea what you might need to do. Have you tried anything yourself yet? If so, what problems are you having specifically?

Comment: if the txt file's contents lines are terminated by a new line just use `file` then implode them by comma

Comment: @TomFenech, i tried many things, and when using explode i always get the following error !
`PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in`

Comment: Sounds like you're passing the wrong values to `explode`. It would be useful if you edited the question to show your attempt and the error message that you're getting.

Comment: @TomFenech, question edited

Comment: So no quotes, only commas and newlines?

Comment: @TomFenech, i asked for any of the options, so if commas only works then sure

Comment: @TomFenech, question updated
sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for more flexibility, you might want to try using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) rather than `explode`, which splits on a regular expression. For example, to split on newlines and commas, you could use this:

```
$text = file_get_contents('text.txt');    
$values = preg_split('/[\n,]+/', $text);
```

Testing it out:

```
$s = "word1,word 2\n word 3";     
print_r(preg_split('/[\n,]+/', $s));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => word1
    [1] => word 2
    [2] =>  word 3
)
```

Putting that into your script:

```
$file = "file.txt";
$text = file_get_contents($file);
$values = preg_split('/[\n,]+/', $text);
```

Then `$values` is an array, which you can loop over in the other script:

```
foreach ($values as $value) {
    // do whatever you want with each value
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: i have also tried to use xml which worked but not as expected, this answer you posted will also remove spaces right ?! i need it to read anything in separate line or anything before a comma, as `word 1, word 2 2, word3,` i need the spaces as well and i need all to be detected as `$value` in `config.php` so that `script.php` can detect any of the words in the list

Comment: I have updated my answer to split on newlines and commas. I'm not sure what you mean in the rest of your comment. You should edit your question to make your requirements clearer.

Comment: No problem. I've suggested some changes to your scripts. The `preg_split` replaces the `explode`. Either way, you shouldn't be using `explode` more than once. Give it a try and see how you get on.

Comment: now i'm getting another error in `script.php`
`explode() [<a href='function.explode'>function.explode</a>]: Empty delimiter in`

Comment: I have no idea what that's about, it's certainly not from the code that I've suggested using. Try my code by itself in a separate file and see what you get. If it's not the right content, then let me know. Otherwise, you need to change other parts of your script that you haven't shown us yet. In general, you need to spend some time trying to make it as clear as possible what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: it worked as long it's in the same file `script.php` and not in `config.php` and i don't have idea why :) 
thanks a lot

Comment: If you `include 'config.php'` in `script.php`, it shouldn't make any difference. Perhaps you're overwriting the variables somewhere? Either way, glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Reading file contents:

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

Explode string:

[explode](http://php.net/explode)

Get file as array (each line => one item):

[file](http://php.net/file)

BTW: a short google would already answer your question...

Answer (score 0):

In config.php add this code, be sure that the file is in the same folder

```
$value = file_get_contents('file.txt');
```

Then in script.php add this code:

```
$pieces = explode(",", $value);
```

Read more about [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). (Click on the names)

Comment: `PHP Warning:  explode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in`