# Extracting the contents of an .rtf file using php

Tags: php, file, rtf

I am having trouble extracting content from a .rtf file in php.
This is the contents of my .rtf file:

> All their equipment and instruments are alive.

I'm on a close deadline right now so any help would be great.

Comment: Did you use the search function of stack overflow? There are plenty solutions which could solve your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get contents from a text file and save it's values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25161372/get-contents-from-a-text-file-and-save-its-values)

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask])

Answer (score -1):

Try using the function file_get_contents().

Details here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php